# TSQL Conditional Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to write a SQL query that does the following:

```
Select * From Table1
```

if there are results, return them. Otherwise, use an alternative query and return it's results:

Select * From Table2

I came ups with the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
IF EXISTS(select * From TableA)
begin
 Select * from TableA 
end
else
 Select * from TableB
```

Is there a simple elegant way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You can only do this in a single query if both tables have the same columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `UNION` query with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1)
```

*Assuming the columns and types are the same

Comment: thanks for the reply, just to clarify if the initial Select returns results the second Select will never fire because the NOT EXISTS will be false.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor That is correct. Or... more technically the second query will fire because it is all one query, but it will return 0 records because the NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

If both tables have same number of columns and the column names are same then you use Union, like below.

```
Select * from TableA
Union
Select * from TableB
```

If they have different column names or different number of columns then you can use below code.

```
Select Col_1 as col1, col_2 as col2.... From TableA
Union
Select col_a as Col1, col_b as Col2..... From TableB
```